# Selling products with a digital variant using Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-digitalproducts

Is it possible to sell products using Craft Commerce, where the product may have digital AND non-digital variants?

For example, a greeting card, might be available as a printed card but also as a digital download.

I know there is a [Digital Products](https://craftcms.com/news/digital-products) plugin - however, this seems to require that the product is either digital OR not (it can't be both):

> Digital products are similar to Commerce’s core products, except that
>   they don’t have variants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could definitely use standard products/variants to sell something that is digitally delivered. The Digital Products plugin just provides a nicer way to verify the ownership of a purchase, but you can see if someone has purchased a particular variant with something like this:

```
{% set orders = craft.commerce.orders.user(currentUser).hasPurchasables(product.defaultVariant).find() %}
{% if orders|length %}
 You already purchased this item in </strong> <a href="customer/order?orderNumber={{ orders[0].number }}">Order #{{ orders[0].shortNumber }}</a>
{% endif %}
```